# Why do a lot of IBM webpages have something like “www-01”?

Tags: domain-name-system, website, ibm

I was looking at this page

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/webphere-business-modeler/advanced/features/

and I noticed that a lot of IBM pages have "www-01." prefix, why is that? I thought every page had either to skip the www. prefix or use just www. Ps. there's a typo too in the page (webphere) but that doesn't matter

Comment: There is no reason to use `www` as prefix. There never was. It might be easier if you have a few boxes and name the one which does ftp ftp.somename.tld, and the one which does gopher gopher.somename.tld, but that is just for easy of maintenance.

Comment: In an environment as complex as IBM's you have a server farm with many different servers. You're confusing a protocol **http/https** with a machine fqdn **www.example.com**. The server could be called **sillyputty.example.com** and as long as it's responding to the **http/https** protocol requests, it will serve web pages. There's nothing special either about not having the **www** as all you're doing is making the machine fqdn be your domain name.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as "too localized" since it only applies to a single company's public website, but I do think the answers about naming standards is useful to have on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`www.` is just a sub-domain and is usually created as a CNAME to the plain domain name. There's nothing inherently special about `www` other than it was the unofficial standard prefix for web traffic way back in the day.

You can have it say `www-i-am-awesome.ibm.com` if you control the authoritative name servers for `ibm.com`, it really doesn't matter. `www.` something isn't any different than `mail.` or `ftp.` or `members.`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

They might have www-02 as their DR site. Or it could be redirected based on the language of your browser, or the region of the world you're in.

Short story - you'd have to ask them, or hope that someone from IBM's web team is here on this site to give the actual answer.